# Conditional formatting & Cell color count?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, counting, add-on, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm using conditional formatting in my google sheet and provide background color on value-based.  My goal is to apply a formula that will automatically count the number of cells that have the same background color. However, the issue is that since they are not color-coded by 'fill color', but based on a conditional formula, I can't seem to find an easy way to count the cells with the same background color.  So please help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to count background color you can use this addon:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-count-and-sum/njiklelndjpdbdngfkdgeijcpfabfgkb

and then you can simply use this formula:

```
=COUNTBACKGROUNDCOLOR("A2:A20", "A3")
```

A2:A20 being the range and A3 being the example of color to count

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks its work, I tried many addons but no one work, so this one works thanks.

Comment: Hi, I have one question regarding this hope you don't mind, How I can count color with the above method if I want to add one more condition I mean I want this formula count color only if Column B is empty. If b column have any value its leave that cell in column a and not count that cell hope you understand

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Thanks, I got a solution for it, anyway thank you so much for your kind help. god bless you.